# How to turn off JPA for SpringBatch under SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

We have a Spring Boot application that uses Spring Integration and Spring Batch.  We drop a file in the poller and it processes.  This process inserts records into a database and then reads them back out does some processing and writes a file.  Let's say there are 10 records.  The first time we get 10 records read and 10 written.  Without stopping the server, we delete all the records through a SQL client on the database, run the same file again and we get 10 records read with 20 written.  I believe there is some JPA or caching going on with the datasource.  We've tried turning off several auto configuration options for JPA and caching but we haven't found the right configuration option to turn off caching.

Adding a bit more detail to the question.

Basically we have cron scheduler that has a FileHandler.  This the handleFile methods we have the following.

```
public File handleFile(File file) throws Throwable {
    JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
    Job job = (Job) appContext.getBean("processInitialFileJob");
    JobExecution jb = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
    ....
}
```

What can we do to the code above to ensure that it has a new JPA session or not use the JPA session at all?  This job needs to read from the database each time and not a cached representation of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up not being an issue with Hibernate or JPA, but an issue of a StringBuilder holding on to data from previous runs.  I believe this will need to be setup as @JobScope so that it is not reused across different executions of the job.

Answer (score 0):

Are u using Hibernate. Hibernate First Level cache may be creating the problem for u. Hibernate manages a First Level cache which is local to your Session. So once u create a session and do any transactions in that hibernate syncs that within. But when u do any changes to the table outside hibernate then hibernate wont sync that until flush is called on the session and session is closed.

To make sure this is not happening, inside your poller logic try creating new Session(or EntityManager in case of JPA) and close the session for every read/process/write cycle.

Also make sure this hibernate.current_session_context_class is not set to Thread. Since thread can be reused by the poller so the same Hibernate Session may be injected again.

Comment: I have a hunch that is the issue.  Is there a way to just turn this completely off?  So basically if I do a read on the table, I want it to actually read the table not a cached representation of the table.